# Protecting references in section headings from capitalization

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, capitalization, acm

I am using the [ACM SIG alternate style](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls), which automatically converts all section titles to upper case. I would like to include a reference in one of the section titles (*Proof of Lemma X*). The obvious way (shown in the MWE below) results in the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `SEC:INTRODUCTION' on page \thepage  undefined on input line 9.
```

Apparantly the argument of `\ref` is converted to upper case before the reference is generated. Is there a way to fix this without changing the label to upper case?

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
The introduction.

\section{The section after Section~\ref{sec:introduction}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the style handy, but would placing a `\protect` prior to the `\ref` help?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, I tried that. I'll add a link to the style.

Comment: Related: [Reference undefined in \section with amsbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13885/35204)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option, `sig-alternate.cls` uses `\uppercase` in `\@sect` to format sectional unit titles; you can patch `\@sect` to use `\MakeTextUppercase` (from the `textcase` package) instead; in this way, the case of any math expressions in the titles won't be changed and the arguments of `\cite`, `\label` and `\ref` will also be prevented from being uppercased:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{textcase}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
The introduction.

\section{The section after Section~\ref{sec:introduction}}

\end{document}
```

In case `xpatch` is not available, one can do the patching using `etoolbox`, in this case, the lines

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother
```

must be replaced with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother
```

(notice that now there's no "x" in the name of the patching command).

Comment: I'm having trouble with the xpatch package, so I can't verify whether this works. It looks like a better solution.

Comment: @Mangara I added to my answer an alternative using `etoolbox` instead of `xpatch`; if also `etoolbox` is not available in your system, let me know and I can give you an alternative with no packages for the patch (the code will be longer, though).

Comment: The `etoolbox` version worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: You should do the patch twice, because `\uppercase` appears twice in `\@sect`

Comment: @egreg Yes, you're right. I've added the missing patch. Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this only works if the `\ref` is **not** protected with `\protect`.

Answer (score 4):

If this isn't too much of a nuisance...

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
The introduction.

\def\x{\ref{sec:introduction}}
\section{The section after Section~\x}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I only need it in a few places, so it's not too much trouble. I'll accept this if no nicer solutions show up.

Comment: @Mangara  Gonzalo's solution is better, though it does require a package load.

Answer (score 0):

After perusing the FAQ some more, I came across [this answer](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a20), which gives another solution:

- Download and incorporate the package
  [lcsect.sty](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/lcsect.sty) into
  your source `.tex` file.
- Use the `\lcsection` command for sections, but convert the text to upper case by hand to stay consistent with the other titles.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{lcsect}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

The introduction.

\lcsection{THE SECTION AFTER SECTION~\ref{sec:introduction}}

\end{document}
```