# Reference (with hyperref) does not work in section heading (shows only question marks)

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices, appendix

[image]I have the following strange problem. I think the minimal working example below is self-explanatory. You can find the imsart-style file [here](https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.ims-aop).

```
\documentclass[aop,preprint]{imsart}
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\startlocaldefs

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{theorem} \label{theo} This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof of \texorpdfstring{\hyperref[theo]{Theorem \ref*{theo}}}{Theorem 1.1}} 

In this section heading the reference does work.

\begin{appendix}

\section{Proof of \texorpdfstring{\hyperref[theo]{Theorem \ref*{theo}}}{Theorem 1.1}} 

In this section heading the reference does not work. Surprisingly, in the table of contents both references work.

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is relevant: [Protecting references in section headings from capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162347)

Answer (score 5):

The class does `\MakeUppercase`, which also transforms the argument to `\ref`.

Use `textcase` with the `overload` option.

Note that I removed the unnecessary `\texorpdfstring`. Also `appendix` is not an environment, use `\appendix`.

Also `\RequirePackage` should be `\usepackage`.

```latex
\documentclass[aop,preprint]{imsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\startlocaldefs

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{theorem} \label{theo} This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{theo}} 

In this section heading the reference does work.

\appendix

\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{theo}}

In this section heading the reference does not work. Surprisingly, in the table of contents both references work.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make the whole “Theorem 1.1” a link by using `\autoref`, but you need to supplement `textcase` list of commands exempt from uppercasing their argument *and* to change the `autoref` name.

```latex
\documentclass[aop,preprint]{imsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\startlocaldefs

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@uclcnotmath}
  {\ref}
  {\ref\@nonchangecase\autoref}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{theorem} \label{theo} This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof of \autoref{theo}}

In this section heading the reference does work.

\appendix
\renewcommand{\theoremautorefname}{THEOREM}

\section{Proof of \autoref{theo}}

In this section heading the reference does not work. Surprisingly, 
in the table of contents both references work.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works, but I would like to keep the hyperref command because I would like that the whole expression "Theorem 1.1" is a blue clickable link, and not only the number. I tried to adapt your answer to the hyperref command, but this does not work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @user144921 - To get a larger clickable target in section 2, just replace `Theorem \ref{theo}` with `\autoref{theo}`.

Comment: I need the `\texorpdfstring` command because I use `\hyperref`.

Comment: \autoref{theo} works fine in the second section. But in the appendix again the question marks appear. This is so strange.

Comment: Where exactly `appendix` environment has been defined in this files?

Comment: I have not defined it anywhere. I used what already exists.

Comment: @user144921 I added as per your request.