# force \ref and math mode to respect letter case when in \section

Tags: cross-referencing, section-titles

I have a strange problem: I have the following section heading:

```
\section{Proof of Result~\ref{{theo:2d.PDF}}}
```

However, the stylefile provided by Wiley `WileyNJD-v2.cls` changes the `ref` in the section heading to upper case, i.e. THEO:2D.PDF and therefore, the reference can not be found.

I tried:

```
\section{Proof of Result~\protect{\ref{{theo:2d.PDF}}}}
```

But get the same problem. What is also bad is that the following:

```
\section{An identity for \protect{${}_1F_1(1,s,z)$}}
```

puts the s, z in the argument of the function in uppercase.

I tried adding the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother
```

from: [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162347/protecting-references-in-section-headings-from-capitalization) without the \protect but I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\NR@sect ...erlinepenalty \@M {\MakeTextUppercase 
                                                  {#8}}\par }\endgroup \else...
```

Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without minimal working example, I can only say that `\MakeTextUppercase` is not a LaTeX kernel command and therefore needs a package like `textcase`. And I could say, that `\protect` before a `{` does not make much sense.

Comment: With a current LaTeX you can use MakeUppercase,  it respect math

Comment: if you have only a few problematic cases you can also simple store them in a macro: `\newcommand\myref{\ref{theo:2d.PDF}}\section{abc \myref}`, \uppercase will leave that then alone. (But it is a bug of the class that it uses \uppercase like this).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks! How do I address the math issue?

Comment: @cabohah, thanks! I guess the comments in the other link are misleading, about `\protect`. Not quite sure how to provide MWE that uses a Wiley style file, but will try.

Comment: in the same way.

Comment: → https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964 and note, that for classes, packages etc. that are not distributed at [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org) it would be useful to add a link to the class or package etc. files.

Comment: Thanks to @UlrikeFischer the probelm is solved.